# WPF adds black bar to Window

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have built a WPF application with a variable width and height (xaml height and width definition for the window is set to `Auto`). Once the contents of the window are loaded, the width does not (well, is not supposed to) change. The height might change as items are removed or added from the list.

The background is a gradient, not an image.

After a period where the application is idling and isn't the top-most, when switching back to the application, the window is wider as a black bar was added, extending the window to the right.
[image: I've blurred out the content as it is unimportant here].
(Before this black bar appears, the window's width is the section with the blue gradient background)

I've added a hidden menu item to the window and when the user presses `Alt` the menu appears. At first, I simply added the menu and opening it caused the window to re-render as menu the item suddenly became visible and added to the window's height. As the window was re-rendered, the black bar disappeared and the window was its original width.

I tried the following solutions by adding an event where `Window.OnFocus` calls a function which:

1. changes the width (adds 1 pixel and then removes 1 pixel)... but this doesn't seem to do anything.
2. checks the width of the window. If the width is larger than the expected width, a re-render is manually called. But no dice...

**What is causing this black bar to appear? How can I prevent it from happening?**

The biggest problem here is that I can't seem to consistently reproduce the problem... sometimes, the application will sit open, idling in the background for the whole day and this won't happen. Sometimes, I'll go out to lunch, come back and there it is...

The content is loaded dynamically upon starting up, and there's a webservice call initiated every few minutes to check for changes. At this stage of development and testing, there aren't all that many changes happening so that the ui items are simply static most of the time. Even so, this black bar will appear at times after the application idles for a while, as mentioned.

---

Per suggestion, here is the xaml for the application:

MainWindow:

```
<Window x:Class="MyApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:y="clr-namespace:MyApp"
        Title="MyApp"
        Height="Auto" Width="390"
        SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"
        WindowStyle="SingleBorderWindow"
        WindowStartupLocation="Manual"
        ResizeMode="CanMinimize">
    <Grid Name="MainGrid" Style="{StaticResource Normal}">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="18" />
            <RowDefinition Height="65"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MinHeight="200"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="150" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="218" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Menu Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
              [SETTINGS REMOVED FOR BREVITY]>
        </Menu>
        [ELEMENTS REMOVED FOR BREVITY]
        <Grid Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" x:Name="ContentGrid"></Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainPanel (which goes into the `ContentGrid`):

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyApp.MainPanel"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             Height="Auto" Width="Auto" FlowDirection="RightToLeft">
    <Grid Margin="19,0,19,0">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="65" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="75" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="160" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="85" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="85" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Name="FirstHeader" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Style="{StaticResource Header}" Text="***" />
        <TextBlock Name="SecondHeader" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Style="{StaticResource Header}">***<LineBreak />***</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Name="ThirdHeader" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" Style="{StaticResource Header}" Text="***" />
        <StackPanel Name="MainStack" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" />
        <Button Name="ActionButton" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Row="2" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" Style="{StaticResource NotInService}"  Click="ActionButton_Click" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

And the `MainStack` in the `MainPanel` is filled with these:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyApp.mItem"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="35" d:DesignWidth="348" FlowDirection="RightToLeft">
    <Grid Margin="0,0,0,05">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="160" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="85" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="85" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Name="PanelActionButton" Style="{StaticResource PanelActionButton}" Click="PanelActionButton_Click">
            <TextBlock Name="AnswerButtonText" Style="{StaticResource ButtonText}"></TextBlock>
        </Button>
        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Name="SecondCol" Style="{StaticResource SecondCol}" />
        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Name="ThirdCol" Style="{StaticResource ThirdCol}" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

I don't know if it's pertinent, but this is the way I've styled the background:

```
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Grid}" x:Key="Normal">
            <Setter Property="Background">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <RadialGradientBrush GradientOrigin="0.5,0.5" Center="0.5,0.5" RadiusX="1" RadiusY="1">
                        <RadialGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                            <GradientStop Color="#00AEEF" Offset="0" />
                            <GradientStop Color="#034ea2" Offset="1" />
                        </RadialGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                    </RadialGradientBrush>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="FlowDirection" Value="RightToLeft" />
        </Style>
```

Comment: You should post xaml code here

Comment: @NguyenKien added xaml, as per your suggestion

Comment: set the window's background to Red . is the black area now red ?

Comment: @eranotzap I set it to red. I will update whether the black area is red, or still black, once the problem I described happens again :)

Comment: I didn't catch that it does not happen each time .
is there a specific part of your xaml that is suppose to be populated in the black area?

Comment: I think it's unusual to set the width and height of the window to auto. Maybe this is causing the problem. Have you tried using SizeToContent="Height" instead?

Comment: On Stack Overflow (and pretty much any other help forum), a request for code is not an invitation for you to dump your entire program to the site. You need to create [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably demonstrates the problem. Please also read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for advice on how to present your question in a clear, answerable way.

Comment: @eranotzap no, there isn't. That black area isn't supposed to be there either. I have no idea what it is, where it comes from.

Comment: @Dominik I have not. I will try it.

Comment: @GuyPassy take notice at what Peter is saying . i wanted to tell you the same thing , but seeing that you dumped every thing here makes you seem clueless . i for one did not read all your code , just small un realated part of it . if you want people to take this seriously please make the effort to put only relevant and minimal code.

Comment: @PeterDuhino Point taken... I'll see what I can do to edit it down to the essentials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some suggestions:

```
SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"
```

could be changed to

```
SizeToContent="Height"
```

since you also defined the width to be 390.
Besides that, check if the window with the black area is still the expected width of 390.

Although it´s not in your posted code, check if elements could extend the width with it´s content (like images, long strings, etc.).

Another thing you should consider is to carefully choose your margins and widths (and heights) since they could easily sum up.
E.g. your using

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="160" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="85" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="85" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

twice and inside grids which each have a margin.

Also have a look at the menu you´re using. Since it´s using some visibility converter, my guess is, that it might generate a menu that could be more than 390 wide.

And finally... what´s with the

```
FlowDirection="RightToLeft"
```

If there´s no real need for it, delete it :)